# Hide scrollbar when not scrolling (Mac like behaviour)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

My Vue web app on Mac browsers shows very elegant scrollbar. But same App on Windows, breaks the UI as the width is too much and the scroll is always visible.

Too solve this issue I created scroll bar from CSS and added event listener to show scrollbar only when it starts to scroll.

```
div * {
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 10+ */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 3px !important;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
.on-scrollbar{
    scrollbar-width: thin; /* Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 10+ */

  }
  
  .on-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  
  .on-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px !important;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .on-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #acacac;
  }
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("on-scrollbar") === false) {
        e.target.classList.add("on-scrollbar");
    }
}, true);
```

But the issue is, once the scroll bar is visible. I am not able to remove/hide the scrollbar when not scrolling. Basically I am trying to implement the default behaviour of scrollbar that we have on Mac.
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this helps. A bit of debouncing and css for scrollbar. If you want to change the style / animation of changing width, there are better resources for that.  Good luck!

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}

window.addEventListener("mousewheel", e => {
  document.querySelector("div").classList.remove("hidden");
});

window.addEventListener("mousewheel", debounce(e => {
  document.querySelector("div").classList.add("hidden");
}));
```

```css
div {
  background: gray;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

div > div {
  background: lighblue;
  height: 800px;
}

/* width */
.shown::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* width */
.hidden::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: black;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: white;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="shown">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("on-scrollbar") === false) {
        e.target.classList.add("on-scrollbar");
    }else{
        setTimeout(function(){
          e.target.classList.remove("on-scrollbar");
     },2000)
    }
 }, true);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, 
[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your answer. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd 
your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both 
the code and the explanations!